# xcode how to import multiple code snippets into IDE

Tags: ios, xcode, code-snippets

I have multiple code snippets i found [here](https://github.com/Xcode-Snippets/Objective-C) and i want to import all of them at once into xcode but it does not work.  When i try to import even just one code snippet from drag and drop from chrome to xcode it imports the url for the snippet instead of the content.

the end goal is to have my entire team share these snippets. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found one way to do this. It seems the code snippet files are plist files generated by xCode IDE.  So from the github hosting the .m files [here](https://github.com/Xcode-Snippets/Objective-C) we can drag and drop into the xcode editor. Highlight the text and drag it into the xcode snippet editor.   Xcode will then generate the plist file associated with each snippet you dragged in.  How to get to these snippets so we can create a repo that your team can share ?  this is how:

1. From your terminal shell traverse to ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData

1b. create a git repo of the
    folder CodeSnippets and call it CodeSnippets

2. If there is already an existing folder called CodeSnippets then rename it to CodeSnippets_old

   3.clone the repo you made in 1b.

   note: might have to restart xcode to see the snippets appear.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very cool app that I believe to be the answer to your problem:

http://cocoaholic.com/snippet_edit/

Comment: how does it import files directly ? it seems to be more suited to grouping the snippets  I was looking for way to import them by simply dragging.  I guess someone would have to supply a plist for each one in order to import.